# Normalizing data sets where some sets may contain incredibly large numbers.

Tags: statistics

The title for this one was a bit difficult to word, so let me explain in a bit more detail (I'm not a mathematician, so please pardon any wrong terminology I use -- corrections are perfectly welcome, though):

I have a few hundred data sets that look something similar to this one:

`[0:76, 1:24, 2:44, 3:15, 4:66, 5:89, 6:40, 7:102, 8:12, ...]`

As you can see, I have indices, which are plotted on X-axis, and values, which are plotted on Y-axis.

I would like to normalize all of this data between values of 0 and 1, so I decided to use the feature scaling formula:

$$X' = a + \frac{(X - X_{min})(b - a)}{(X_{max} - X_{min})}$$

Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_(statistics)

One problem, though, is that some of the data sets may have incredibly large values, when compared to the rest of the sets:

`[0:12000, 1:8909, 2:9045, 3:1001, 4:289, 5:6784, 6:3400, 7:1899, 8:1023, ...]`

So, when all of these get plotted after normalization, it looks like most of the data is at near-zero, with only large-value sets being visible. While, technically, it's correct and scaling was done properly, I would like to set some sort of limit and if a value exceeds that limit it just stays there. So, values at or above limit would be plotted as 1, while the rest of the values would be below that, but would still be visible.

I was toying around with how I can get this done, and was thinking of perhaps using the mean as the limit.... but the mean is highly influenced by these few large-value data sets. So, I'm having a bit of a difficulty determining the limit.

Edit:

Clarification on my notation in the above data sets:
`X:Y` -> `X` is the X-axis value (point in time), `Y` is the Y-value (value at that point in time).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_scale

Comment: (1) Your notation is not familiar to me. Does `2:44` mean that the value 2 was observed 44 times? If not that, what does it mean? (2) In both of your examples, the first number runs from 0 to 8. What is the largest value you have? (3) Why do you want to put everything on a scale from 0 to 1? (4) Can you tell us what these number are? ('Index" isn't very descriptive.) And what conclusions you want to try to draw for the data?

Comment: @BruceET
(1) `2` is the X-axis (timeline) value, while `44` is the value at that point in time.
(2) There are arbitrary number of values. 0 to 8 in my examples are X-axis timeline points, followed the values found at those points.
(3) To analyze them side-by-side.... basically the UI has a bunch of these graphs and it's easier to compare if they're normalized. Used as a visual way to determine high-activity areas.

Comment: @saulspatz Thanks, looking into that right now.

Comment: What is your goal? If the large values are few, then perhaps they are outliers that shouldn't be considered.

Comment: @GitGud That's the problem, I don't know how many of these large-value data sets are there at any given point in time, this is all dynamically generated data in a program.

Comment: This might be worth a post over at [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). I think it is OK to cross-post.

Comment: I think @saulspatz had the right solution for this one. Logarithmic normalization might do the trick. Going to test tonight.

Comment: Glad to help out.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to do a cutoff, you might want to use the $75^{th}$ percentile or something like that.  You might want to use $1.5$ times the $75^{th}$ percentile so that nothing goes off the top if you don't have a few large values.

As saulspatz mentioned you can take the log of the $y$ values to bring the large ones more in line.

Another approach is to plot two graphs, one incorporating the small values and one incorporating the large ones.  Again the cutoff might be based on the percentile.

Maybe the important thing in your data is whether the data set is large or small and the variation between the small ones is not important.  This would say the scaling you are doing is fine.

You need to decide what is the important thing to show.

Comment: Yep, did logarithmic scaling as @saulspatz suggested and it worked like a charm.